# Securing Token Authentication in Laravel 10 with Separate Vue 3 Client

Tags: laravel, security, laravel-sanctum, websecurity, sanctum

I'm encountering an issue with token security in my Laravel 10 project using Sanctum for authentication and a separate Vue 3 client. Our setup involves using APIs to manage authentication and data processing.

The problem arises when a user logs in via the API, as Sanctum generates a token. I noticed that I could extract this token from the browser's app data and use it in Postman to access all data associated with the user. This presents a security vulnerability that I need to address.

I'm wondering if there's a more robust solution to prevent this scenario, particularly considering that our Vue 3 client is separate from the Laravel project and not using Inertia. Any insights or recommendations on improving token security in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are your tokens httponly?

Comment: AFAIK, with httpOnly cookies, js is not able to access/manipulate cookies. Though it does not stop people to manually copy the said httpOnly cookies in Application>Cookies.

Comment: I have used API token, its not spa token. So there is no cookies

Comment: I see. I might have mixed my knowledge with tokens.